# HTTPClient recomendations

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I created a webclient customizer that creates a `HTTPClient` with a custom `ConnectionProvider`

```java
    @Bean
    WebClientCustomizer webClientCustomizer(CustomizableWebClientProperties properties) {
        return builder -> {
            var connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider
                .builder("customizable-webclient-connection-provider")
                .maxConnections(properties.maxConnections())
                .maxIdleTime(properties.maxIdleTimeout())
                .build();
            var httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider).compress(true);
            httpClient.warmup().block();
            if (properties.wiretap()) {
                httpClient = httpClient.wiretap("uk.co.something.webclient", LogLevel.DEBUG, TEXTUAL, UTF_8);
            }
            var connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            builder.clientConnector(connector);
        };
    }
```

And I have several questions:

- should/could `ConnectionProvider` instance be shared with `HttpClient` that are created in that customizer?
- Is it best to use a `HTTPClient` per domain/endpoint or could it be shared? There are several services in the app that build their own webclient instance.

Appart from those, any other recommendation is more than welcome!

Comment: It is better to share LoopResource, ConnectionProvider, SslContext etc.

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva therefore should I create one HTTPClient instance per WebClient and share one instance the ConnectionProvider (outside the lambda or as a Bean) ? Why  is best not to share HTTPClient across WebClient Instances?

Comment: You can share one HttpClient with many WebClients (if you want to create many WebClients)

Comment: The app has to call different services (several methods each) with different base paths, I thought that inject the web client builder and build an instance for each one was the recommended approach. @VioletaGeorgieva if you post an answer I will accept it (you are directly involve with reactor-netty development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scenario allows, it is always better to share common resources as LoopResource, ConnectionProvider, SslContext etc.
By default, if there is no explicit configuration, Reactor Netty will share those.

The same applies for HttpClient and WebClient. If the scenario allows, it is always better to share HttpClient and WebClient.